How can I prevent my Bootstrap carousel from overflowing?

I am building a portfolio with bootstrap and I have carousal on the top, but it is overflowing more which make it to scroll horizontally.
Carousal html
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img src="img/animewallpaper7.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="img/animewallpaper8.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="img/animewallpaper9.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="img/animewallpaper6.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
  </div>

here is my css
/* Ensure the carousel spans the full width of its container */
.carousel {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto; /* Center the carousel within its container */
    
}

/* Remove extra padding and margin around the images */
.carousel-item img {
    width: 100%;  /* Ensures the image covers the full width of the item */
    height: 600px; /* Adjusts the height based on the width */
}

I need the carousal to be in the size of browser without overflowing and still be responsive as it is

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

Don't tag multiple versions. That's confusing.

This seems like an issue with your overall layout and not just the carousel. Plase show that. You can present a working demo using the editor. Also, it's bad practice to apply styles to core Bootstrap classes like carousel. That shouldn't be necessary, but if it is it should be done with either existing Bootstrap classes or custom classes.

I am going to assume you are using the latest bootstrap, bootstrap 5. What you just need to do is to make every parent of the image is 100% in height starting from body and html.


html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.carousel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel-item {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://placehold.co/600x400");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>




It's been clarified that Bootstrap 4 is at play.

This is a short answer, but I hope it can be useful.
Your question doesn't show this, but from my experience this can happen when you place your full-width carousel inside of a container.
Carousels already have the proper container inside the item div, so they don't need to be nested in a container.

I found a fix. But, As I have found from the comments this does not correctly fix the error properly. As it is adding to html this will force the page image not to go 100% width of screen but i will simply hide the overflowing part so it is not a good solution.
html {
overflow-x: hidden; /* Prevents horizontal scrolling */

}

That's not really a fix, it's a correction for something that has gone wrong. It would be better not to do the wrong thing in the first place. Also, have you lost interest in your own question now that you think you have a fix? Please edit your question to include code that can actually reproduce your problem.

And you absolutely should not be applying such a heavy-handed style to the top-level element on your document.

this will force the page to not go 100% width of screen but it will cut the screen size and it's not good solution.
